# Dynamic SQL in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run a select statement in Snowflake using dynamic SQL, and pass in approximately a million WHERE conditions as a parameter in a loop.

Let's say I have a base_table A1 with 4 columns: APP_NUMBER, STATE, PRODUCT, AGE.

Using the table A1, I created a new_table to show all possible combinations for STATE, PRODUCT, and AGE with A1 as the prefix for every output in the first column. This new table has two columns named TEXT_STRING and GROUPING. Added an example below of the output for more clarity.

```
TEXT_STRING                            GROUPING
A1.STATE='NY'                          1
A1.STATE='NY' AND A1.PRODUCT='HOME'    2
A1.STATE='PA' AND A1.AGE=45            3
```

I want to select all records in TEXT_STRING as my conditions in the select statement and return a count of total APP_NUMBER from base_table A1 in each TEXT_STRING condition.

Is there a way to run a loop through every condition and return the results in a separate table?

Thanks!

I find lots of examples for Javascript but nothing too specific for SQL. Please let me know if this possible in Snowflake. Thanks again!

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: I just updated to show it as editable text. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear, to me, why you are taking this approach. If you just want counts of what's in your main table then use COUNT and GROUP BY. If you want all possible combinations  of STATE, PRODUCT, and AGE (regardless of whether there are matching rows in your main table i.e. these will give counts of zero) then create a table with these 3 columns and every combination of values, left join this to your main table and do a COUNT... GROUP BY again

Comment: Those 3 columns were just examples. I have close to 680K combinations that I need to test as conditions. 'TEXT_STRING' column would show all those combinations in SQL syntax. I am trying to figure the top combinations that are performing well and use it for other purposes.

Comment: @NickW I tried using a snowflake scripting block variables too but I am still unable to make it work. It's either returning all records in the count (which is not I am looking for) or returning null in my alternate approaches. Are you able to help by any chance? Here's where I posted the detailed code and the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76434216/15287936