# Dynamic SQL in Snowflake

Tags: sql, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

When I run a dynamic SQL in snowflake, I am running into the following error:

Assignment to 'SQL_MAIN' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 263; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).

Here is the code:

```
SET v_G = '1';
SET v_G1 = $v_G::VARCHAR;
SET v_P = (SELECT "txtstr" FROM table2 WHERE "grouping" = $v_G);
SET SQL_MAIN = 'CREATE TABLE N_1 AS
                SELECT a1.YEARMONTH as "DATE",
                COUNT(a1.RECORD_NUM) AS "COUNT",
                ' || $v_G1 ||' AS "GROUP"
                FROM table1 a1
                WHERE ' || $v_P || ' GROUP BY YEARMONTH';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $SQL_MAIN;

set d_max_row = (select count(*) from table2");

begin
    let counter :=1;
        while (counter <= $d_max_row)
        do
            SET v_G = $v_G+1;
            SET v_G1 = $v_G::VARCHAR;
            SET v_P = (SELECT "txtstr" FROM table2 WHERE "grouping" = $v_G);
            SET SQL_MAIN = 'INSERT INTO N_1 (DATE, COUNT, GROUP)
                            SELECT a1.YEARMONTH as "DATE",
                            COUNT(a1.RECORD_NUM) AS "COUNT",
                            ' || $v_G1 ||' AS "GROUP"
                            FROM table1 a1
                            WHERE ' || $v_P || ' GROUP BY YEARMONTH';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $SQL_MAIN;
           
            counter := counter + 1;
        end while;
    return counter;
end;
```

Is there a way to run a loop through every record in "txtstr" column from table2 as a condition in table1 and return the results in a separate table?

I find lots of examples for Javascript but nothing too specific for SQL. Please let me know if this possible in Snowflake.

Thanks!

Comment: `SET` is for session variable. I suggest switching to Snowflake Scripting block variables - [How to increase Variable size limit in Snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70997220/5070879)

Comment: I tried that, but I was unable to make it work. Would you be able to show me with the example I provided?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I have tried it various ways but I am still unable to make it work. It's either returning all records in the count (which is not I am looking for) or returning null in my alternate approaches. Are you able to help by any chance?

Comment: Please update your question with your latest SQL scripting code - either pick the version that return the count or that returns null, whichever one you think is closer to the “correct” code

Comment: @NickW The question I have posted right now is as close as I got to running the code. When the size of the variables is less than 256 characters, it works - I tested it by limiting the variable v_P to return the results only within the permitted length. I am trying to figure out if there's any other way to make this work as I need everything that's in "txtstr" column to run.

Comment: As @LukaszSzozda commented, I think you need to convert this to a Snowflake Scripting block in order to achieve what you want. The documentation to get you started is probably this page here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets

Comment: Thank you both! I appreciate the responses and I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments - let me construct a full example of what Lukasz and NickW are saying.

Let me start reproducing the error with this `set`:

```sql
set long_string = (select array_generate_range(1,100)::string);

-- Assignment to 'LONG_STRING' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 289; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).
```

As your goal is to construct long sql strings to be executed, this is a minimal example that constructs long sql strings and executes them:

```sql
declare 
    long_string default (select array_generate_range(1,100)::string);
    sql_to_execute string;
    rs resultset;
begin
    sql_to_execute := $$ select $$ || long_string;
    rs := (execute immediate sql_to_execute);
    return table(rs);
end;
-- [   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,   65,   66,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,   76,   77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,   87,   88,   89,   90,   91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,   99 ]
```

The secret is to avoid `set`, and instead declaring your variables in the `declare` block.

Comment: Thank you! This example helped and I was able to figure it out